# Solidity: Send some money to myself

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a question from Solidity, and my IDE is use Remix, I want to send some money to my self.

**My Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract toMyself{

    address owner;

    function toMyself()public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function Send(uint x)public payable{
        owner.transfer(x);
    }
}
```

**But when I press the Send button, it will show me a message like:**

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: HI, before that did you click toMyself()?

Comment: HI Jimmy Lee, but toMyself is the constructor, them don't have a button.My Deployed Contracts just one button is "Send".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Are you sure that the contract has enough ether available to send?
2. Don't you prefer switching

```
function Send(uint x)public payable{
    owner.transfer(x);
}
```

to

```
function Send()public payable{
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

So you send to the owner whatever is coming into the smart contract?

Also, you can send back whichever quantity has just been sent to the msg.sender in this way:

```
function SendBack() public payable{
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

But this will end being useless and wasting some gas.

Comment: Hi, I use the "Ropsten test network" to create my contract, so I have enough ether to let me practice. And I hope I can sent any quantity ether to myself when I have enough ether.

Comment: @Danielkuo What i meant is that with your code you are sending x wei from the smart contract to the owner. Without taking into account the quantity available to the smart contract itself.
With my code, you will be sending to the owner whichever quantity the sender has sent.

Comment: Also I have edited the answer to reflect a SendBack functionality.

Comment: OK I understand what your mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked your code in remix and it works, i just used solidity compiler version 0.5

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;
contract toMyself{

address owner;

 constructor() public{
    owner = msg.sender;
}
function Send(uint x)public payable{
    msg.sender.transfer(x);
}
}
```

maybe its because of the no amount in the contract. Secondly when you use Send the uint value should be in wei.

For the domination units 
http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ether.html

Comment: that's very lucid.

Comment: Ok, now I have another question:
https://imgur.com/a/q4DZatr .

I don't know what the problem going on?

Comment: Try this in metamask Accounts->Settings-> Reset Account

Comment: It didn't work, but I guess I know where the problem is. I didn't set the GAS FEE, but it can work after I set the GAS FEE. So, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I am just clarifying @Fernando's answer here.

```
function Send(uint x) public payable {
    owner.transfer(x);
}
```

here x amount of wei will be sent to owner's account **form contract's balance**. For this to happen your contract needs to hold at least x amount of wei. Not the account that is calling `Send` function. **Note:** here `Send` function need not be marked as `payable`.

Now in case of

```
function Send() public payable {
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

caller of `Send` function will send some amount of `ether/wei` along with the request. We can retrieve that amount using `msg.value`. Then transfer it to the owner's account. Here the contract itself does not need to hold any amount of ether. **Note:** here `Send` function has to be marked as `payable`.

Comment: OK I got it. SO, now I just want to send some ether from my address to my address, isn't it possible?

Comment: Yes. Theoretically it is possible. But I'm curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Please teach me how to do that. I'm a beginner at solidity, and I just want to do like "hello world!" a simple coding. So I have this idea to do this.

Comment: Find some tutorials on [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) or [blockgeeks](https://blockgeeks.com/) or similar websites. [this](https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-and-solidity-the-complete-developers-guide/) is a good place to start.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple functions to do that but right now (2022) the recommended method is to use the `call` function like this:

```
function sendETH(address payable _recipient) public payable {
    // pass the value you want in Wei
    (bool wasSent, bytes memory data) = _recipient.call{value: 1 ether}("");
    require(wasSent, "Failed to send Ether");
}
```